# PlayFramework 2.5 failed to run using Netty Transport Native

Tags: scala, netty, playframework-2.5

i am having trouble to run Play Framework application. Following is the details of the application:

1. PlayFramework 2.5.0
2. SBT 0.3.11
3. Scala 2.11.7
4. Dependencies in SBT

   ```
   object Dependencies {
     // Repositories
     val resolutionRepos = Seq(
       "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/",
       "scalaz-bintray" at "https://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases",
       "Atlassian Releases" at "https://maven.atlassian.com/public/",
       "Couchbase Maven repository" at "http://files.couchbase.com/maven2",
       "Maven Repository" at "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2",
       "MVN Repository" at "http://central.maven.org/maven2",
       Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots"),
       Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases"),
       Resolver.url("sbt snapshot plugins", url("http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-snapshots"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns),
       Resolver.url("mcveat.github.com", url("http://mcveat.github.com/releases"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
     )

     // Versions
     object V {
       val Activation = "1.1.1"
       val Akka = "2.4.2"
       val AkkaQuartz = "1.4.0-akka-2.3.x"
       val AwsScala = "0.5.3"
       val CommonIo = "2.4"
       val CommonNet = "3.3"
       val CommonCodec = "1.10"
       val CommonMail = "1.4.7"
       val CommonLang = "3.4"
       val CouchbaseClient = "2.1.6"
       val CouchbaseCore = "1.1.6"
       val Dispatch = "0.11.3"
       val Elastic4s = "1.7.4"
       val Fluentlenium = "0.10.3"
       val Guice = "4.0"
       val Guava = "19.0"
       val Inject = "1"
       val HttpClient = "4.3.6"
       val HttpCore = "4.3.3"
       val Jackson = "2.7.1"
       val Jerkson = "0.6.7"
       val JodaTime = "2.9.2"
       val JodaConvert = "1.8.1"
       val Junit = "4.12"
       val LiftJson = "2.6.2"
       val Logback = "1.1.4"
       val Mockito = "1.10.8"
       val Netty = "4.0.34.Final"
       val PlayMailer = "3.0.1"
       val PostgresDriver = "9.4-1206-jdbc42"
       val ScalaGuice = "4.0.0"
       val ScalaTest = "2.2.4"
       val ScalaPlayTest = "1.4.0-M3"
       val ScalaVersion = "2.11.7"
       val ScalaModules = "1.0.3"
       val Selenium = "2.45.0"
       val Silhouette = "4.0.0-BETA1"
       val Slf4j = "1.7.16"
       val Spec2 = "2.3.12"
       val Spray = "1.3.3"
       val SprayJson = "1.3.2"
       val TypeSafeConfig = "1.3.0"
       val TypeSafePlay = "2.5.0"
     }

     val activation = "javax.activation" % "activation" % V.Activation
     val akkaActor = "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % V.Akka
     val akkaKernel = "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-kernel" % V.Akka
     val akkaQuartz = "com.enragedginger" %% "akka-quartz-scheduler" % V.AkkaQuartz
     val akkaSlf4j = "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j" % V.Akka
     val akkaTestKit = "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % V.Akka % "test"
     val awsScala = "com.github.seratch" %% "awscala" % V.AwsScala
     val commonIo = "commons-io" % "commons-io" % V.CommonIo
     val commonNet = "commons-net" % "commons-net" % V.CommonNet
     val commonCodec = "commons-codec" % "commons-codec" % V.CommonCodec
     val commonMail = "javax.mail" % "mail" % V.CommonMail
     val couchbaseClient = "com.couchbase.client" % "java-client" % V.CouchbaseClient
     val couchbaseCore = "com.couchbase.client" % "core-io" % V.CouchbaseCore exclude("com.fasterxml", "*")
     val commonLang = "org.apache.commons" % "commons-lang3" % V.CommonLang
     val dispatch = "net.databinder.dispatch" % "dispatch-core_2.11" % V.Dispatch exclude("org.scala-stm", "scala-stm_2.10.0")
     val elastic4s = "com.sksamuel.elastic4s" %% "elastic4s-core" % V.Elastic4s
     val email = "play.modules.mail" %% "play2-mail-plugin" % "0.6"
     val fluentlenium = "org.fluentlenium" % "fluentlenium-core" % V.Fluentlenium % "test"
     val fluentleniumFest = "org.fluentlenium" % "fluentlenium-festassert" % V.Fluentlenium % "test"
     val guice = "com.google.inject" % "guice" % V.Guice
     val guava = "com.google.guava" % "guava" % V.Guava
     val inject = "javax.inject" % "javax.inject" % V.Inject
     val httpClient = "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient" % V.HttpClient
     val httpCore = "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpcore" % V.HttpCore
     val jacksonCore = "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % V.Jackson
     val jacksonBind = "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % V.Jackson
     val jacksonAnnotation = "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-annotations" % V.Jackson
     val jacksonDataType = "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype" % "jackson-datatype-jdk8" % V.Jackson
     val jdbcPostgres = "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % V.PostgresDriver
     val jerkson = "com.gilt" % "jerkson_2.11" % V.Jerkson exclude("org.scala-stm", "scala-stm_2.10.0") exclude("play", "*")
     val jodaConvert = "org.joda" % "joda-convert" % V.JodaConvert
     val jodaTime = "joda-time" % "joda-time" % V.JodaTime
     val junit = "junit" % "junit" % V.Junit % "test"
     val liftJson = "net.liftweb" %% "lift-json" % V.LiftJson
     val liftJsonExt = "net.liftweb" %% "lift-json-ext" % V.LiftJson
     val logbackCore = "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-core" % V.Logback
     val logbackClassic = "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % V.Logback
     val mockito = "org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % V.Mockito % "test"
     val scalaGuice = "net.codingwell" %% "scala-guice" % V.ScalaGuice
     val scalaTest = "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % V.ScalaTest % "test"
     val scalaPlayTest = "org.scalatestplus" %% "play" % V.ScalaPlayTest % "test"
     val selenium = "org.seleniumhq.selenium" % "selenium-java" % V.Selenium % "test"
     val silhouette = "com.mohiva" %% "play-silhouette" % V.Silhouette
     val silhouettePasswordBCrypt = "com.mohiva" %% "play-silhouette-password-bcrypt" % V.Silhouette
     val silhouetteTestKit = "com.mohiva" %% "play-silhouette-testkit" % V.Silhouette % "test"
     val slf4j = "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % V.Slf4j
     val sprayCan = "io.spray" %% "spray-can" % V.Spray
     val sprayHttp = "io.spray" %% "spray-http" % V.Spray
     val sprayJson = "io.spray" %% "spray-json" % V.SprayJson
     val sprayRouting = "io.spray" %% "spray-routing" % V.Spray
     val sprayTests = "io.spray" %% "spray-testkit" % V.Spray % "test"
     val specs2Core = "org.specs2" %% "specs2-core" % V.Spec2
     val specs2JUnit = "org.specs2" %% "specs2-junit" % V.Spec2 % "test"
     val specs2Matcher = "org.specs2" %% "specs2-matcher" % V.Spec2 % "test"
     val specs2Mock = "org.specs2" %% "specs2-mock" % V.Spec2 % "test"
     val typeSafeConfig = "com.typesafe" % "config" % V.TypeSafeConfig
     val typeSafePlayCache = "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-cache" % V.TypeSafePlay
     val typeSafePlayDb = "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-jdbc" % V.TypeSafePlay
     val typeSafePlayDbApi = "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-jdbc-api" % V.TypeSafePlay
     val typeSafePlayEvolutions = "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-jdbc-evolutions" % V.TypeSafePlay
     val typeSafePlayFilter = "com.typesafe.play" %% "filters-helpers" % V.TypeSafePlay
     val typeSafePlayJson = "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % V.TypeSafePlay
     val typeSafePlayMailer = "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer" % V.PlayMailer
     val typeSafePlayTest = "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-test" % V.TypeSafePlay

      // Dependencies to be overriden due to some libraries are the latest version of each
     lazy val overrideDependencies = Set(
       activation,
       akkaActor,
       akkaSlf4j,
       akkaTestKit,
       commonCodec,
       commonLang,
       commonMail,
       guava,
       httpClient,
       httpCore,
       jacksonAnnotation,
       jacksonBind,
       jacksonCore,
       jacksonDataType,
       jodaConvert,
       jodaTime,
       junit,
       logbackCore,
       logbackClassic,
       slf4j,
       typeSafeConfig,
       typeSafePlayCache,
       typeSafePlayJson,
       "commons-logging" % "commons-logging" % "1.2",
       "com.ning" % "async-http-client" % "1.9.21",
       "net.sourceforge.htmlunit" % "htmlunit" % "2.20",
       "io.netty" % "netty" % "3.10.1.Final",
       "io.netty" % "netty-all" % V.Netty,
       "io.netty" % "netty-codec-http" % V.Netty,
       "io.netty" % "netty-handler" % V.Netty,
       "io.netty" % "netty-transport" % V.Netty,
       "io.netty" % "netty-buffer" % V.Netty,
       "io.netty" % "netty-common" % V.Netty,
       "com.google.code.findbugs" % "jsr305" % "3.0.1",
       "org.bouncycastle" % "bcprov-jdk15on" % "1.51",
       "org.javassist" % "javassist" % "3.20.0-GA",
       "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-parser-combinators" % "1.0.4",
       "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-xml" % "1.0.4",
       "com.typesafe.play" %% "play" % V.TypeSafePlay,
       "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-netty-server" % V.TypeSafePlay,
       "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-server" % V.TypeSafePlay,
       "xml-apis" % "xml-apis" % "1.4.01"
     )
   }
   ```
5. Plugins.sbt

   ```
   // Scoverage Plugin
   addSbtPlugin("org.scoverage" % "sbt-scoverage" % "1.1.0")

   // SBT Native Packager
   addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" %% "sbt-native-packager" % "1.0.2")

   // Play Plugin
   addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.0")

   // Assembly Plugin
   addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.11.2")

   addSbtPlugin("com.jamesward" % "play-auto-refresh" % "0.0.13")
   ```
6. Build.scala

   ```
   object TIBuild extends Build {

     import BuildSettings._
     import Dependencies._

     // configure prompt to show current project
     override lazy val settings = super.settings :+ {
       shellPrompt := { s => "[TI PROJECT] " + Project.extract(s).currentProject.id + " > " }
     }

     BrowserNotifierKeys.shouldOpenBrowser := false
     JsEngineKeys.engineType := JsEngineKeys.EngineType.Node

     //... Multi projects description here, nothing significant to this issue ...
   }
   ```
7. Partial config in reference.conf (No application.conf in the app):

   ```
    
   play.server {
     netty {
       transport = "native"
     }
   }
   ```

This jar **netty-transport-native-epoll-4.0.33.Final-linux-x86_64.jar** is available in the '/lib' folder of the dist file (as a transitive dependencies).

However, when i run the app in the staging server (Ubuntu 14.0.4), i got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/channel/epoll/EpollDatagramChannel$DatagramSocketAddress
ti-portal-1 | 2016-03-18T07:06:35.675317263Z    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
ti-portal-1 | 2016-03-18T07:06:35.675447058Z    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1938)
ti-portal-1 | 2016-03-18T07:06:35.675583984Z    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1821)
ti-portal-1 | 2016-03-18T07:06:35.675698092Z    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
ti-portal-1 | 2016-03-18T07:06:35.675823281Z    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
ti-portal-1 | 2016-03-18T07:06:35.675943125Z    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:193)
ti-portal-1 | 2016-03-18T07:06:35.676114343Z    at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.(Native.java:48)
ti-portal-1 | 2016-03-18T07:06:35.676239448Z    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventArray.(EpollEventArray.java:40)
ti-portal-1 | 2016-03-18T07:06:35.676448982Z    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.(EpollEventLoop.java:66)
ti-portal-1 | 2016-03-18T07:06:35.677077555Z    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoopGroup.newChild(EpollEventLoopGroup.java:76)
ti-portal-1 | 2016-03-18T07:06:35.677223247Z    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:64)
ti-portal-1 | 2016-03-18T07:06:35.677354357Z    at io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:49)
ti-portal-1 | 2016-03-18T07:06:35.677547627Z    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoopGroup.(EpollEventLoopGroup.java:61)
ti-portal-1 | 2016-03-18T07:06:35.677719684Z    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoopGroup.(EpollEventLoopGroup.java:49)
ti-portal-1 | 2016-03-18T07:06:35.677842651Z    at play.core.server.NettyServer.(NettyServer.scala:74)
ti-portal-1 | 2016-03-18T07:06:35.678233662Z    at play.core.server.NettyServerProvider.createServer(NettyServer.scala:266)
ti-portal-1 | 2016-03-18T07:06:35.678384523Z    at play.core.server.NettyServerProvider.createServer(NettyServer.scala:265)
ti-portal-1 | 2016-03-18T07:06:35.678501026Z    at play.core.server.ServerProvider$class.createServer(ServerProvider.scala:25)
ti-portal-1 | 2016-03-18T07:06:35.678623815Z    at play.core.server.NettyServerProvider.createServer(NettyServer.scala:265)
ti-portal-1 | 2016-03-18T07:06:35.678734335Z    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.start(ProdServerStart.scala:53)
ti-portal-1 | 2016-03-18T07:06:35.678842600Z    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.main(ProdServerStart.scala:22)
ti-portal-1 | 2016-03-18T07:06:35.679050486Z    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart.main(ProdServerStart.scala)
ti-portal-1 | 2016-03-18T07:06:35.679298166Z Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollDatagramChannel$DatagramSocketAddress
ti-portal-1 | 2016-03-18T07:06:35.679410387Z    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
ti-portal-1 | 2016-03-18T07:06:35.679522334Z    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
ti-portal-1 | 2016-03-18T07:06:35.679632600Z    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
ti-portal-1 | 2016-03-18T07:06:35.679775126Z    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
ti-portal-1 | 2016-03-18T07:06:35.680094183Z    ... 22 more
```

Tried to google but found nothing to solve this issue. Any kind of suggestion/advice to solve this would be very appreciated.

Comment: I think you have some other dependencies that are pulling a previous version of netty. There is no info in your question to provide more help. Normally you would not need to override dependencies.  And the configuration of the play.server should be done in application.conf but it is also optional.  Also please review, SBT and scala versions.

Comment: What kind of info i can provide to help? the reason i override dependencies cause when i run sbt evicted command, sbt suggested to use "netty-3.10.1.Final" (which also added to my override dependencies)

Comment: Post your build.sbt and your plugins.sbt.

Comment: Done. Updated my post above. Hopefully it hellps. Thanks for your effort, guys.

Comment: Dependency overrides is used to select one version in case of there are more than one and there is no incompatible binary conflicts. Netty 3.10 and netty 4.0 should not be in your override dependencies.  You might need to upgrade the library that depends on netty 3.10 before migrating to play 2.5.

Comment: @JonasAnso Thanks for the advice, but i've spent days just trying to get play 2.5 to use netty transport native without any good result. So i will just revert back to 'jdk'.

Comment: It is a pity! Anyway enjoy Scala.